# Read/write info to open Excel spreadsheet with VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have code that reads/write to an Excel .xlsx file from VB.net.  However I don't have a method to read/write to an Excel spreadsheet that is open.  I need to be able to read/write to an open Excel spreadsheet such that the edits can be seen within the open spreadsheet.

Created the code below, and it works with test.xlsx file on disk.  It does not read/write with the copy of test.xlsx in memory and visible in Excel.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
xlWorkBook = GetObject("C:\test.xlsx")
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("testtab")
xlWorkSheet.Activate()

MsgBox(xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 2).value)  ' returns "this is B5" from spreadsheet
xlWorkSheet.Cells(6, 2).value = "this is new B6"
MsgBox(xlWorkSheet.Cells(6, 2).value)

xlWorkBook.Save()
```

Need for code to "see" the visible image of test.xlsx opened with Excel.  Any data entered into test.xlsx via Excel by keyboard should be readable by VB.net.  Any data entered into test.xlsx via VB.net should be visible to user with spreadsheet opened in Excel.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations !

Comment: Are you saying that `xlWorkBook = GetObject("C:\test.xlsx")` does not retrieve the workbook instance?  It should.  I would get rid of `xlApp = New Excel.Application`.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  Yes ... GetObject appears to interact with the spreadsheet file on disk, even though the spreadsheet is open at the time in Excel.  I want VB to interact with Excel, not just read/write to the .xlsx file on disk.

Comment: BTW ... I commented out "xlApp = New Excel.Application" but didn't see any difference in execution.

Comment: xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks("test.xlsx")

Comment: Genius.  It worked.  Greatly appreciated !